# Javascript: looping through an array of objects that hold arrays

Tags: javascript, loops, leaflet, mapbox

In leaflet, I made a function that takes an array holding objects that each hold an array of markers and an ID to identify the group.

I have this array:

```
var markerGroupArray = [
{ features: [L.marker([39.61, -105.02]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.'),
L.marker([39.74, -104.99]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.'),
L.marker([39.73, -104.8]).bindPopup('This is Aurora, CO.'),
L.marker([39.77, -105.23]).bindPopup('This is Golden, CO.')], id: 'Group 1'},

{ features: [L.marker([39.51, -105.02]).bindPopup('Somewhere else'),
L.marker([39.64, -104.99]).bindPopup('Somewhere else'),
L.marker([39.63, -104.8]).bindPopup('Somewhere else'),
L.marker([39.67, -105.23]).bindPopup('Somewhere else')], id: 'Group 2'}
];
```

Which I feed to this function:

```
addOverlayMap: function (overlayMapArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < overlayMapArray.length; i++)
    {
        var layerGroup = L.layerGroup();

        for (var j = 0; j < overlayMapArray[i][features].length; j++)
        {
            layerGroup.addLayer(overlayMapArray[i][features][j]);
        }

        this.overlayMapObject[overlayMapArray[i][id]] = layerGroup;
    }
    this.refreshLayerControl();
}
```

However, I get the error that the "features" key is not defined. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`overlayMapArray[i][features].length` should be `overlayMapArray[i].features.length` (no `[]` around `features`). Or alternately, if you prefer, `overlayMapArray[i]['features'].length` (in JavaScript, you can do either).

What your code is currently doing is trying to use the value of a variable called `features`; since you don't have one, you get a `ReferenceError`. By switching to a literal (my first suggestion) or brackets notation and a string (my second suggestion), you're specifying the property name `features`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of what went wrong!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
overlayMapArray[i]['features']
```

Comment: Surrounding features in quotes worked perfectly! Thanks.